# PySpark dataframe join on customized join condition

Tags: dataframe, join, pyspark

I have `df_a, df_b`, I want to join them on a customized condition: `coalesce(df_a.id, 0) + 1 == df_b.id`, how should I write the code?

I tried `df_joined = df_a.join(df_b, coalesce(df_a.id, 0) + 1 == df_b.id`)

But got error: `Invalid argument, not a string or column: 0 of type <type 'int'>. For column literals, use 'lit', 'array', 'struct' or 'create_map' function`

Comment: you need to use 'lit'. Just do a little change as shown below. It will work.  from pyspark.sql.functions import lit
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

cond=F.coalesce(df_a.id, lit(0)) + 1 == df_b.id
newdf=df_a.join(df_b,cond)